# Scrapy: How do I get text and text with <b> tag at the same time when using scrapy and xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I need to get 183.7 from the html below

```
<span class="price"><b>183</b>.7</span>
```

but if run below code with scrapy shell mode, only '.7' is available

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()').get()
```

How shall I write the code to get complete number?

I have read Scrapy tutial at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.7/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors
but it is still hard for me to understand the right xpath setting to get values I need.

If I try

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]').get()
```

it returns

```
['<span class="price"><'b>183</'b>.7 </span>']
```

which is also not what exactly I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "//" to get all child text on the element like this:

```py
"".join(response.xpath('//span[@class="price"]//text()').extract())
```

Comment: It worked to get values but they look like '183', '.7', '202', '.4', '299', '302', '.3' so it is hard to concatenate. Using .join also seems difficult, because there are sometimes value like without '.x' value.let me know if you have a good idea to get 183.7 as one value.

Comment: I only depends on you problem description that if your html is not only have an `class=price`, you should traverse the elements which you need. Then take out the each element data.